# Installing and Configuring Mercurial on Jenkins application -OpenShift

Tags: configuration, mercurial, openshift

Any hints on how doing this? I tried with the auto-install from a downloaded zip from this [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/mercurial-2.2.1.tar.gz), extracted here: OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/hg and executable location here: OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jenkins/data/tools/Mercurial/mercurial-2.2.1/bin/hg

I'm doing something wrong for sure, I'm not Linux saavy. Jenkins says is unable to find mercurial executable.

Any help is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer from [here](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/installing-and-configuring-mercurial-on-jenkins-application):

Thanks for the email discussion.

### Mercurial includes a README which explains a couple of modes of execution:

Basic install:

$ make # see install targets
$ make install # do a system-wide install
$ hg debuginstall # sanity-check setup
$ hg # see help

Running without installing:

$ make local # build for inplace usage

### $ ./hg --version # should show the latest version

"make install" will not work as it attempts to do a system-wide install. The user on the gears will not have access to write to system files.
"make install-home" will not work either.

"make local" works and will install it in cwd such that running the following will should work just fine:

```
./hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.2.1)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)
```